# How to find the value of an arbitrary constant for which a system of linear equations has no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find the value of the constant *a* for which the following system of linear equations has no solution:

$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+0x_2+x_3=1 \\ 
2x_1+x_2+3x_3=1 \\ 
0x_1+x_2+ax_3=3
\end{array}
\right.$

I made this into an augmented matrix:

$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\2 & 1 & 3 & 1\\0 & 1 & a & 3   \end{array} \right]
$

...and tried to bring it into rref:

$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1 & -1\\0 & 0 & a-1 & 4   \end{array} \right]
$

But I'm at a loss for how to proceed. I searched this problem and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659885/solving-linear-systems-with-arbitrary-constants) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131947/find-the-value-of-k-if-any-for-which-the-system-below-has-unique-infinite-o) but didn't understand the answers provided. Could anyone tell me how to proceed and find the value of a for which the system has no solution?

Comment: The system is inconsistent if there’s no pivot in the third row, but the entry on the right side is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation with $-2$ and adding to the secvond we have
$$x_2+x_3=-1$$
$$x_2+ax_3=1$$
and from here we obtain
$$x_3(a-1)=2$$
can you finish?

Comment: Realised I incorrectly copied the linear equations. It's actually

 $\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+0x_2+x_3=1 \\ 
2x_1+x_2+3x_3=1 \\ 
0x_1+x_2+ax_3=3
\end{array}
\right.$


What operation did you perform to get x_3(a−1)=2?

Comment: i have the same System as you, i Subtracted the both equations